# MySQL Query is not getting prod_id for a product whose image in not added yet.

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query it is returning records if i check in databse but as click on product title it does not shows prod_id for those products whose image is not present.

Product can also have multiple images but i dont know how to write a query to only get 1 image and if image is not present then no image will be displayed with product.

Sorry for my wrong english.

Plz assist me.

```
SELECT * from tbl_sc_products AS p 
LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u ON p.user_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_sc_prod_img AS pi ON pi.prod_id = p.prod_id 
WHERE p.user_id = (36) AND p.cat_id IN(45,82,81,80,212,213,468,469) 
GROUP BY p.prod_id 
ORDER BY p.prod_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Do use LEFT OUTER JOIN on the "LEFT JOIN tbl_sc_prod_img AS pi ON pi.prod_id = p.prod_id" line. This will tell SQL not to ignore that line, if nothing is found on the right side :)